# Parse PFQueryTableViewController with custom cell and UISearchbar

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I have a PFQueryTAbleViewController which queries Parse and displays result in custom cells with a PFImageView and a UILabel

My Goal is to add a search bar which can filter the results based on data shown in the TableView.

I found many exemples for regulars TableViewControllers but not for PFQueryTableViewController with custom cells...

Oh and I am using Swift not ObjC.

Here is my code :

```
class UserListViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    NSLog(searchText)
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
    query?.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
    return query!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UserListTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UserListTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell!.userName.text = ((object?.objectForKey("firstname"))! as! String) + " " + ((object?.objectForKey("lastname"))! as! String)
    let imageFile = object?.objectForKey("avatar") as? PFFile
    cell!.userAvatar.file = imageFile
    cell!.userAvatar.loadInBackground()
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: have you found any solution for this problem as I'm too unable to add search

Comment: Nope... What I did is a regular TableView and just used a PFTableViewCell for convenience.